# .click function in jquery always have to get a nameless function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hallo all. I have a little problem.

I have a function. Let’s call it :

```
function rowClick ()
{

}
```

Anyway, the question is:

How can I bind this function to a click event without it being called?

What I mean is, if I do this:

```
$("#holder").click (function(){ rowClick(); });
```

the `rowClick` function gets called while registering it to the click event.

Anyway I understand why this happens. I just don’t understand how I can bind the function to the event in a way that it won’t be called.

Thanks.

Comment: it gets called because you put `()` after it, which means "call the function on the left."

Comment: But this should only happen when the anonymous funtion is invoked and that, in turn, should only happen when the click event fires. I suspect that the OP has sanitised the code in his post, thereby masking the true problem.

Comment: in the code you posted, rowClick doesn't get called when registering the click event--it only gets called when the click actually happens. Did the question originally have this code: `$("#holder").click (rowClick());` ??

Comment: nope it didnt.

i had a mistake. i explained it here:

i found out fnRowCallback got called for each cell... and not each row like excpected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the function() and parenthesis from the function name, ex:

```
$("#holder").click(rowClick);
```

Comment: forgot to mention i have parameters i need to pass to that function..

how do i do that without the parentetis?

Comment: Create a second parameterless function that calls the other function with the correct parameters.

Comment: Then you should revert to the anonymous function technique - which should work. Can you post some more of the surrounding code?

Comment: Paul - that would work, but it seems like overkill to me, as the original code should work fine.

Comment: here it is:

"fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDispalyIndex)
                {
                    var currRow = $(nRow);
                    currRow.attr("docId", aData[1]);
 
                    currRow.click(function ()
                    {
                        alert("here");
                        DocGridRowClick(this, aData[1]);
                    });
 
                    return nRow;
                }

i use the datatables plugin and that its fnrowcallback

Comment: found the problem. the problem was that fnRowCallback
is being called after each cell in the row or something like that.
its being called a few times for each row.

then it assigned my function manytimes and that why i thought it is being called

Comment: That's not how you hook-up to the fnRowCallback (unless you are attempting to mimick what this does via another link?) - this is it's own function callback separate from the click() provided in jQuery (that is, you don't need jQuery's click at all). See this link for details to do what you want: http://www.datatables.net/usage/callbacks - click on the Show Details link.

Comment: So, next time you post a question, could you make it even remotely resemble the actual code? Glad you've solved your problem though.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
$("#holder").click (rowClick);
```

...although the anonymous function should not be invoked (and, therefore, neither should rowClick) until the click event occurs.

Comment: lol thats what i thought but now when you said it i found out i have a bug.

for some reason when i later click on a row its being triggered a few times not just once...

Answer (score 0):

You just have to pass a **function reference** as parameter. That does not neccesarily mean an `anonymous function`.

The call

```
$("#holder").click ( rowClick );
```

will work just fine. Don't forget to redesign your `rowClick` function with an `event parameter`:

```
function rowClick (event) {
   alert(event.target.id);
}
```

This parameter is passed in automatically and can be accessed within your callback function.